# How to Use IF Statement in Play Framework to Use CSS for Only 1 Page

Tags: html, css, scala, playframework

I have one page in particular that uses a stylesheet however none of the other pages within my website use it so I do not want to put it in the global main.scala.html file as all pages will then reference it. How can I make an IF statement in the play framework to say that when testpage.html is active, use teststylesheet.css?

Comment: Does the stylesheet need to be added in the header? Or would the sub view suffice?

Comment: I'd rather have it just added to the header.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Figured out what I needed was this in the main.scala.html:

```
@if(activeMenu.equals("pricing")){
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="@routes.Assets.at("stylesheetname.css")">}
```

Answer (score 2):

According to [the official docs](http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/JavaTemplateUseCases) you can use ***moreScripts and moreStyles equivalents*** approach:

```
@(title: String, css: Html = Html(""), scripts: Html = Html(""))(content: Html)

<!-- language: lang-html -->
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
    <head>
        <title>@title</title>
        <!-- common stylesheets <link rel="stylesheet"> -->
        @css

        <!-- common scripts -->
        <script src="xyz.js")        
        @scripts
     </head>
     <body>
        @content
     </body>
</html>
```

and in sub template

```
@css = {
    <link rel="stylesheet" media="screen" href='@routes.Assets.at("stylesheets/teststylesheet.css")'>
}

@scripts = {
    <script src='@routes.Assets.at("javascripts/test.js")' type="text/javascript"></script>    
}

@main("title", css, scripts) {
     <div class="bodyOfView">rest of templating...</div>
}
```

**Other option** is using separate *layouts* containing only required JS / CSS for the given page.